# Cómo hacer para aplicar '!important' de CSS con jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cómo aplicar `!important` a una propiedad CSS vía jQuery o Javascript?
Ejemplo de código:

```
$('#elem').css('height','50px!important');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La mejor manera de aplicar reglas CSS siempre es usando clases.
Así lo mejor es siempre establecer una clase en CSS para manejarlo:

```
.claseImportante {
    height: 50px!important
}
```

```
$('#elem').addClass('claseImportante ');
```

Pero además de esa forma ideal de hacerlo, podría hacerlo directamente con Javascript de la siguiente manera utilizando [`setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) que tiene un parámetro para la importancia:

```
document.getElementById('elem').style.setProperty('height', '50px', 'important');
```

> O jQuery:

```
$('#elem')[0].style.setProperty('height', '50px', 'important');
```

O

```
$('#elem').attr('style', function(i,s) { return s + 'height: 50px !important;' });
```

Comment: Una respuesta muy completa. Como nota: al último ejemplo la falta un punto y coma (`;`) antes del `height`. Si no se pone, puede haber problemas en dos casos: si la etiqueta no tiene atributo `style`, o si la última última regla del `style` no tiene un `;` al final

Comment: En realidad, lo **ideal es no usar important**, ya que su uso es una **mala práctica**.  _El uso de !important, **es una mala práctica y debería evitarse** porque hace que el **código sea más difícil de depurar** porque **rompe la cascada natural de las hojas de estilo**. Cuando dos declaraciones en conflicto con el !important son aplicadas al mismo elemento, se aplicará la declaración con mayor especificidad._ https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad

Answer (score 2):

Ya tienes una buena solución, yo te voy a poner una alternativa si lo quieres hacer con jQuery. Podrías usar `$(elemento).css("cssText", "tus-estilos-aquí")` donde "cssText" es el valor completo de los estilos (equivalente a hacer  `elemento.styles.cssText` en JavaScript puro).

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$("#elem").css("cssText", "height:50px !important");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>A</div>
<div id="elem">B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

---

El problema es que eso va a sobreescribir todo lo que haya en los estilos inline (dentro del atributo `style`), por lo que sería conveniente que añadieras los estilos antes para que no se pierdan. Algo como esto:

```js
$("#elem").css("cssText", $("#elem").attr("style") + ";height:50px !important");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>A</div>
<div id="elem" style="color:red">B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

Comment: Superbe! Gran solucion